# Executing external python script function

Tags: python, import

I have two scripts in the same folder:

5057_Basic_Flow_Acquire.xyzpy

5006_Basic_Flow_Execute.xyzpy

I need to call function run() from 5057_Basic_Flow_Acquire file in the 5006_Basic_Flow_Execute file.

I tried two approaches:

1.

```
import time
import os
import sys
import types

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
#os.chdir(str(dir_path))
sys.path.append(str(dir_path))
sensor = __import__('5057_Basic_Flow_Acquire')
```

2. 

```
import time
import os
import sys
import types

import importlib
import importlib.util
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('run', dir_path+'\\5057_Basic_Flow_Acquire')
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
```

Pycharm is reporting this type of errors:

1. case:
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '5057_Basic_Flow_Acquire'
2. case
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

So in both cases module was not found.
Does someone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should rename your files to something like :
5057_Basic_Flow_Acquire_xyz.py
5006_Basic_Flow_Execute_xyz.py
so that they are recognized as modules and can be imported.

Then, in your 5057_Basic_Flow_Acquire_xyz module, you can import the run function with the following line :

```py
from 5006_Basic_Flow_Execute_xyz import run
```

Both files are in the same directory, so you should be able to import without changing your PATH environment variable as the current directory is automatically added at the top of the list.